# Efeito Fade corrido em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom, vou tentar explicar da melhor forma, o que pretendo fazer:

Tenho uma div com o id de borda, que na verdade a div serve de borda.

Pretendo fazer um efeito em jQuery, corrido de troca de cores, de cima para baixo, ou seja está vermelho, depois vai ficando laranja, amarelo, verde etc...

Basicamente é fazer com que a div mude de cor com fade e corrido...

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui: [CSS Gradient Border](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-gradient-border/)

Comment: É tipo isso, Douglas, só que quero que as cores estejam sempre a ser corridas em tempo real com jquery

Comment: posta o que voce ja tem de codigo brother

Comment: Não tenho código, por isso que pretendo fazer isso.

Comment: Você precisa que seja animado as cores? Se sim, não use jQuery para isso, o próprio CSS já tem um recurso chamado _CSS Animations_. Crie nesse site sua animação de cores, e altere o código de acordo com o que precisa para sua "borda", use `background` ao invés de `border-color`. [CSS Gradient Animator](https://www.gradient-animator.com/)

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: @Gonçalo se você não se deu o trabalho de pesquisar e aprender para tentar alguma coisa, quem somos nós para te ajudar? Não estamos aqui para trabalhar para você, mas sim para ajudar a resolver problemas que você encontrou no meio do desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se é exatamente o que procura, mas de alguma forma já pode te dar uma idéia do que fazer.

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```css
.divA {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(89deg, #c3dd39, #39c6dd, red);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: anim 30s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: anim 5s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: anim 5s ease infinite;
  animation: anim 5s ease infinite;
}

.divB {
  background: #fff;
  width: 390px;
  height: 390px;
  margin: 0px auto
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="divA">
  <div class="divB">
    Teste
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente! Muito bom, era mesmo isso que eu precisava.